# Передать значения js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как передать значения переменной (координаты местонахождения) в я.карту?

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 
<div id="map" style="width:450px;height:300px"></div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
        zoom: 9,
        controls: []
    });
    // Получение гео от браузера - СЮДА ЗАГАНЯЮ КООРДИНАТЫ ПОЛУЧЕННЫЕ ОТ БРАУЗЕРА
    
      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
  const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords;
        });
        
  
     // Создание маршрута.
    var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        referencePoints: [
            [latitude, longitude],- //НО СЮДА УЖЕ НЕ ПЕРЕДАЕТ, ЛОМАЮ ГОЛОВУ НЕ МОГУ ПОНЯТЬ ПОЧЕМУ!
           [53.1231331,68.12412412]
        ]
    }, {
        boundsAutoApply: true
    });
   
 
    // Добавление маршрута на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
 
    // Подписка на событие обновления данных маршрута.
    multiRoute.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function() {
        // Получение ссылки на активный маршрут.
        // В примере используется автомобильный маршрут,
        // поэтому метод getActiveRoute() вернет объект multiRouter.driving.Route.
        var activeRoute = multiRoute.getActiveRoute();
        // Вывод информации о маршруте.
        console.log("Длина: " + activeRoute.properties.get("distance").text);
        console.log("Время прохождения: " + activeRoute.properties.get("duration").text);
        // Для автомобильных маршрутов можно вывести 
        // информацию о перекрытых участках.
        if (activeRoute.properties.get("blocked")) {
            console.log("На маршруте имеются участки с перекрытыми дорогами.");
        }
    }); 
    // Добавление маршрута на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);   
}); 
</script>
```

Я сделал так, но это не помогло

```
 let latitude;  // global scope
let longitude; // global scope
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( ( position ) => {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        })
```

Comment: const {latitude, longitude} = position.coords; в другой области видимости. Вынесите декларацию переменных на уровень выше.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Не совсем силен в js, можете на примере показать что не так?

Comment: @Believe можете заменить const {latitude, longitude} на var {latitude, longitude} и оно будет работать. Но это не лучшее решение

Comment: Заменил на var, не работает...

Comment: Константы latitude и longitude создаются в области видимости функции обратного вызова (navigator.geolocation.watchPosition) и поэтому не "видны" при создании маршрута. Декларируйте переменные после коментария // Получение гео от браузера, например, так: let lat, long; а значение присваивайте в функции обратного вызова.

Comment: Можете пример подсказать?